# Writing error code and its string message: Scala

Tags: scala

I am storing error code and its string message in this way:

```
object Error {
  def FileNotFound(filename: String) = Error("ERR01", s"${filename} not found")
  def UserNotExist(userName: String) = Error("ERR02", s"${userName} not exist")
}

case class Error(code: String, value: String) {}
```

Benefit of keeping it like this is that I can pass string value to error message.

And I am creating it like

```
def validate(data: SomeType): List[Error] = {
    var errors = ListBuffer[Error]()
    if (validation1("abc") == false) {
      errors+= Error.FileNotFound("abc")
    }
    if (validation2("lmn") == false) {
      errors+= Error.UserNotExist("lmn")
    }
    errors.toList
}
```

I am new to Scala and functional programming. 
Is it right way to write error code like this? 
Is it following functional programming paradigm?

Scala: 2.11

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What do those functions within the object have to do with the case class? I'm not sure what you're trying to do here as the question lacks context.

Comment: it seems fine to me. didn't get the question what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @RamanMishra thanks for quick reply. Is the code is correct way to achieve same? Since I am new to functional programming, I don't know in case it is violating any of its core concept.

Comment: Overriding `Error` in any JVM language is not a good idea, because of the omnipresent `java.lang.Error` - choose a more specific name. It's unclear what we are supposed to tell you about functional programming if there is not a single function anywhere in your code?

Comment: you can use apply method and pattern matching to do the Custom exception handling.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin I added sample code where I am creating validation error list.

Comment: @RamanMishra I don't want to create exception, as single validation will be sending multiple validation messages. Creating exceptions means one validation per run. I wanted to list all validation error in one go

Comment: `: List[Error] {` - what, this is supposed to compile, really? And... no, that's not following functional programming style. In functional programming style you would concentrate on solving the problem, and stash all the annoying error accumulation away in some applicative effect. Your `validate` doesn't seem to produce anything useful, all it returns are errors.

Comment: You might find [this rather detailed introduction to `Validated`](https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/validated.html) useful (even though I cannot guarantee that it will be pleasant to use with 2.11).

Comment: Coming late to the party but, I would like to say that if you are really new to the language, I would suggest you to `Either` and use your mutable approach. Then, when you become more comfortable with the language and with the functional paradigm, switch to use `ValidatedNec` _(As Andrey said)_ or any other kind of **Aplicative** which lets you abstract over the _error accumulation_ **Effect**.

Comment: You can make that code functional without using advanced constructs and making the code looks nice and "focusing on solving the problem" can come after he understood the basic principles. Plus, he asks a way of collecting errors only and not having also the original data.

Answer (score 2):

Here are my two cents with a full example.

I assume you want to do this in nice-and-easy functional style, so let's remove the mutable `ListBuffer` and see how to deal with it. The description of the steps are after the code.

**UPDATE:** I want to note that, in your code, the usage of `ListBuffer` is acceptable because it doesn't break [rerefential transparency](https://www.sitepoint.com/what-is-referential-transparency/). This is because you don't expose its mutable nature outside the function and the output of the function depends only on its inputs.

Nonetheless I usually prefer to avoid using mutable data if not for specific reasons, like compactness or performance.

```
object StackOverflowAnswer {

  /* Base type with some common fields */
  class MyError( val code: String, val msg: String )

  /* FileNotFound type, subtype of MyError, with its specific fields */
  case class FileNotFound( filename: String ) extends MyError(
    "ERR01", s"$filename not found"
  )

  /* UserDoesntExist type, subtype of MyError, with its specific fields */
  case class UserDoesntExist( userName: String ) extends MyError(
    "ERR01", s"$userName doesn't exist"
  )

  /*
   * Validates the file. If it finds an error it returns a Some(MyError) with
   * the error that's been found
   * */
  def checkForBadFile( data: String ): Option[MyError] =
    if( data.contains("bad_file.txt") )
      Some(FileNotFound("bad_file.txt"))
    else
      None

  /*
   * Validates the user. If it finds an error it returns a Some(MyError) with
   * the error that's been found
   * */
  def checkForMissingUser( data: String ): Option[MyError] =
    if( data.contains("bad_username") )
      Some(UserDoesntExist("bad_username"))
    else
      None

  /*
   * Performs all the validations and returns a list with the errors.
   */
  def validate( data: String ): List[MyError] = {
    val fileCheck = checkForBadFile( data )
    val userCheck = checkForMissingUser( data )
    List( fileCheck, userCheck ).flatten
  }

  /* Run and test! */
  def main( args: Array[String] ): Unit = {
    val goodData = "This is a text"
    val goodDataResult = validate( goodData ).map( _.msg )
    println(s"The checks for '$goodData' returned: $goodDataResult")

    val badFile = "This is a text with bad_file.txt"
    val badFileResult = validate( badFile ).map( _.msg )
    println(s"The checks for '$badFile' returned: $badFileResult")

    val badUser = "This is a text with bad_username"
    val badUserResult = validate( badUser ).map( _.msg )
    println(s"The checks for '$badUser' returned: $badUserResult")

    val badBoth = "This is a text with bad_file.txt and bad_username"
    val badBothResult = validate( badBoth ).map( _.msg )
    println(s"The checks for '$badBoth' returned: $badBothResult")
  }

}
```

I start defining the type structure for the error, similar to your.

Then I have two functions that performs validations for each check you want. When they find an error, they return it using the Option type of Scala. If you're not familiar with Option, you can have a look [at this link](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/using-scala-option-some-none-idiom-function-java-null) or do some googling.

Then I have the validation function that calls and store each the above single checks. The last bit is the use of `flatten` ([doc here](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Seq.html#flatten[B]:Seq[B])) that "flattens" `List[Option[MyError]]` into `List[MyError]`, removing the middle `Option`.

Then there is the actual code that shows you some examples.

Comment: Your `validate` function can just use `flatten` rather than `collect`

Comment: In Scala 2.13 you will be able to do `Option.when(test)(error)` which will be nice :)

Comment: Nice! Any link to that?